# Enum variable initialization

Tags: java

I call this method receives as parameters a String and a Type (which is a enum)

```
 static OCalasa o=new OCalasa();
 String serie=v[2];
 Enumerare tip;
 o.AdaugaVehicul(new Masina(serie,tip));
```

This is the enumeration

```
public enum Enumerare
{
    DIESEL,BENZINA,NONE
}
```

Error I receive is this:

"variable tip might not have been initialized"

So, the variable "type" must be initialized.

What I do know is to be initialized?

I want to read from a keyboard command like "add 543 DIESEL" and only then to execute the method.

This is myMethod:

```
  Vehicul[] v1=new Vehicul[10];
  int n;
  public void AdaugaVehicul(Vehicul v)
  {
      if(n<100)
      {
          v1[n]=v;
          n++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the variable `tip` an initial value before using it

```
Enumerare tip = Enumerare.NONE;
```

Comment: and if I put NONE and write "add 333 DIESEL" working?

Answer (score 1):

"variable tip might not have been initialized" means that the variable `tip` has been set to any value. This is a problem of the variable declaration, not the enum class declaration.

This, for example, would compile just fine:

```
Enumerare tip = Enumerare.DIESEL;
o.AdaugaVehicul(new Masina(serie,tip));
```

So would:

```
Enumerare tip = null;
o.AdaugaVehicul(new Masina(serie,tip));
```

Comment: And you can write "add 333 Anything"? 
The method calls and so and I want to call only for cases "add 333 DIESEL", "add 555 BENZINA", "add 432 NONE"

Answer (score 1):

> "variable tip might not have been initialized"
>   So, the variable "type" must be initialized.

I guess you mean "tip" - if so, you are right. You are declaring a variable "tip" of type `Enumerare` but you are not assigning any value to it. One example to assign a value would be

```
Enumerare tip = Enumerare.DIESEL;
```

If you don't use initialization of this variable but you are trying to access it later in your program, of course the compiler will tell you that there might be problems with it.

And to be honest: I don't understand the second part of your question, so I only answer the first one. Hope this helped anyways.